# show success message after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to show a message when i update the statement but the button type is submit when i do that it refresh the page and the message wont show when i change the button type to button it shows the message but don't do the update action this is my codes
**html code**

```
<div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="success-alert">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> User Name Changed Succsefully
  </div>
 <div class="row">


  <div class="col-md-6">
    New username:  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="New username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto my-1">


       <button type="submit" name="changeuser" id="user" class="btn btn-primary">change username</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**java code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user").click(function() {
    $('#success-alert').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#success-alert').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
  });
      $("button.close").click(function() {
    $('#success-alert').addClass('hidden');
  });

});
```

**php code**

```
if (isset($_POST['changeuser']))
{

  $username=$_POST['user'];
  $sql="SELECT * from user_account where username='$username'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
            {
              echo '<script language="javascript">';
                  echo 'alert("User name already exits Please Chose Another One")';
                 echo '</script>';
            }
            else
            {
               $up = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user_account SET username='$username' WHERE id='$id'");

            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your php code as this:

```
$up = '';
if (isset($_POST['changeuser']))
{

  $username=$_POST['user'];
  $sql="SELECT * from user_account where username='$username'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
            {
              echo '<script language="javascript">';
                  echo 'alert("User name already exits Please Chose Another One")';
                 echo '</script>';
            }
            else
            {
               $up = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user_account SET username='$username' WHERE id='$id'");

            }

}
```

And change your html section like this:

```
<?php 
if($up) {
?>
<div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> User Name Changed Succsefully
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```